# Android: How to check if users date is valid

Tags: android, date

I know there are a lot of questions asked that are related to this but they all seems not to solve my problem.
I want to check if the date on the user's device is correct, start an activity but in a case where the date on the users device is wrong, it should show an error activity that asks the user to adjust their date just like how whatsapp implemented theirs..

[image]

Comment: Please add some code to show what you tried. Or your question will be soon marked close.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must have server's timestamps to determine if the time in device is fake.
[Npt pool](http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/) is a free service to help you get true timestamps.
To use, device must ONLINE, you can not check without the Internet.
Copy class **SntpClient** to your project: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/net/SntpClient.java

Code:

```
SntpClient client = new SntpClient();
long now = -1;
if (client.requestTime("pool.ntp.org", TIME_OUT)) {              
      now = client.getNtpTime();
      if (Math.abs(now - System.currentTimeMillis())    >= ONE_DAY){ 
           // the device's time is wrong
           startErrorActivity();
           ...
      } else {
           // the different time lower than 1 day
           startNextActivity();
      }
} else {
      // something wrong, can't get server's time          
}
```

Don't forget add `INTERNET` permission to your manifest

Comment: How do I achieve this when the device is not connected to network?

Comment: ONE_DAY means.!!

Comment: `client.requestTime` is now always return `false`.